# Change parameters in HTTP web requests

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

Hey Guys i'm very new to Web development. I used the fetch API to send a http request as shown below. It worked well. But now i want to change the second parameter(ie the IP address) when I execute a sql query. So the idea is to execute the sql query into the place where the IP is everytime i press a button in the webpage. Is it possible to set a variable for the sql query and write that variable in place of the IP? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
 fetch("    http://192.xx.x.xxx/abc-bin/output?username=one&password=xxxx&action=on&pin=relay")
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
```

Comment: yes it is ... you can do all sorts of things with strings, and the url in fetch is just a string - of course, how are you going to "execute sql" in a browser?

Comment: Do the SQL query, then in the callback function that processes the results, concatenate the IP you fetched from the DB into the URL.

Comment: It is important to note that you're not actually modifying SQL here. You're adapting an HTTP Request that looks like is calling out to REST API. The server receives HTTP Request, interprets them and executes a code that will interact with the database on your  behalf, abstracting the SQL language out of the interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a very common task in javascript. You have a number of options to solve this. How you set the variables will depend on your front-end javascript click handlers or html attributes on the buttons themselves.

Option 1 - String concatination

```
// Create a variable with the IP or Domain you would like to replace with
// If you didn't know domains are mapped to IPs, so you can use each inter-changably


// Example variables
const protocol = 'https://'
const domain = 'www.stackoverflow.com'
const path = '/abc-bin/output?username=one&password=xxxx&action=on&pin=relay'

// Concatinate to create single string
const url = protocol + domain + path

fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
```

Option 2 - String Interpolation

```
// Example variables
const domain = 'www.stackoverflow.com'

// Interpolate string...NOTE they aren't single quotes but 
// are backticks (top left key on US keyboard)
// You must wrap your variables with ${variableName} to
// have it interpreted as a string
const url = `https://${domain}/abc-bin/output?username=one&password=xxxx&action=on&pin=relay`

fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
```